# too many groups have influence in weight painting

Tags: rigging

[image]

[image]

Hi guys,
I am new to weight painting in Blender and I need your help.
Here are 2 images that show the problem I am currently encountering.
When I smooth weight between 2 bones, some low value weights are scattering into many other vertex groups causing unwanted influence when posing character.
So is there any way of preventing weights going into other groups?
I tried to use subtract brush to remove some of the weight but removing them causing those weights appear in other unwanted vertex groups.
Also, my mesh is pretty dense and I have a lot of vertex groups so removing vertices from many groups takes too long to complete. 
Any advice? and thank you in advance :)